# Reading datatable value of one feature from another feature in specflow

Tags: background, specflow

i have a feature called as create experiment in feature1, i am passing the data that is needed to create experiment as Background section of feature file 1.

i want to access the data i am passing from feature file1 into feature file 2 as precondition. before executing featurefile2 i want to make sure the experiment is present with the data given in feature file1.

i am using a common class to collect all the data used in feature file 1 instead of storing them in stepdefination .
following the example given in this link to achieve this. https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Context-Injection.html

The problem here is, when i run feature file2 alone it does not get the data, since to data is filled during execution of feature file 1.

How to read the data of featurefile1 without executing featurefile1.

how to solve this .

Comment: I don't think we can provide a good answer without more information. We need to see the SpecFlow tests and some of the step definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the state of another test is generally not the idea on how to do BDD tests, or any unit/integration tests in general, since they are supposed to be self-contained. Understandably there won't be any support in SpecFlow on how to do this.

The easiest solution I can think of is to either copy the step definitions to your second feature file, which then calls the same code again. You don't have to copy the test implementation, because all steps are global in SpecFlow by default.

Another solution would be to add a background to the second feature file where you simply call the methods of the first feature file.